# jQuery Form plugin, how to receive data from php

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery Form plugin to upload images to my server. After upload server send message which says if upload is succesful or not, I would like to receive this data any display a message according to received data but I'm not doing it right. Since I coulnd't find suitable information on their official page I'm asking here. This is how I submit images:

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
.
.
.
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadForm">
                    <label id="uploadLabel">Add new background</label><br>
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/*"><br>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" id="uploadButton">
                </form>

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$("#uploadButton").click(function(){
        $('#uploadForm').ajaxForm({url: 'upload.php', type: 'post'}, function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
```

Then I process image in upload.php and then I should receive some data from this script but I don't receive anything.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing my code to this:

```
$("#uploadButton").click(function(){
        $('#uploadForm').ajaxForm({url: 'upload.php', type: 'post'}, function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form){
            console.log(responseText);
        });
    });
```